# Como poner borde diagonal entre 2 div

Tags: html5, css3

Estoy creando un portafolio y quiero colocar 2 secciones juntas separadas con un borde diagonal sin margenes, ambos divs tienen texto y colores distintos, estuve buscando en internet, pero no en encuentro lo que busco, he intentado varias cosas pero ya llevo un buen rato no lo consigo, estoy intentando de esta forma:

```css
.info-card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.info-card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

#info {
  background: #cc6600;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#info::after {
  background: #cc6600;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  right: 0;
}

#history {
  background: #0066cc;
  float: right;
}

#history::after {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  bottom: top left;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="info" class="info-card">
  <h1>Título 1</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="history" class="info-card">
  <h1>Título 2</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
  </p>
</div>
```

Pero los bordes están encima del texto ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: Agrega a tu css `h1,p{position: relative;z-index: 200;}`

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez gracias, pero el texto pasa los bordes

Comment: Ponle un padding left si es el de la derecha o padding right si es el de la izquierda. Una alternativa hubiera sido usar clip-path, pero no tiene gran soporte.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías aplicar esta posible solución aunque seguirías teniendo problemas en pantallas muy pequeñas.

Si has conseguido el resultado que buscabas de otra forma me gustaría conocerla.

```css
.container{
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height:500px
}
.info-card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.info-card::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-20deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

#info {
  background: #cc6600;
  width: 50%;
  background: #cc6600;
  float: left;
}

#info::after {
  background: #cc6600;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  right: 0;
}

#history {
  background: #0066cc;
}

#history::after {
  background-color: #0066cc;
  bottom: top left;
  left: 0;
}

#info h1,
#info p{
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10vw;
    padding-right: 15vw;
}
#history h1,
#history p{
    z-index: 4;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10vw;
    padding-right: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="info" class="info-card">
  <h1>Título 1</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </p>
</div>
<div id="history" class="info-card">
  <h1>Título 2</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit
  </p>
</div>
</div>
```